# How can you write a while loop to run parallel processes on Unix ssh?

Tags: parallel-processing, sh

I have a script file that contains different case IDs of a factorial Design of Experiment (DoE). I also have a script file run on MATLAB. I am attempting to run multiple cases of this DoE at once, 25 to be exact, and only up to 25 at once. The current input to the ssh server looks like the following (the batch file):

```
InputFile=inputfile.txt
count=0
while read -r case; do
echo $case
nohup matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -r "try;runinput=$case;matlab_script;end;exit"
((++count % 25 == 0)) && wait
done <"$InputFile"
```

This however, only reads the first line of the inputfile.txt and runs that, and does not run the other 24 processes at the same time. I have tried getting rid of the && wait part but it still doesn't do what I want. How can I make it start the 24 other jobs in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And alternative to GNU Parallel, there's GNU xargs with its `-P` option:

```
xargs -P25 -d'\n' -I{} -t matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -r "try;runinput={};matlab_script;end;exit" < inputfile.txt
```

In bash you could use `wait -n` to wait for a single child, something along:

```
count=0
while IFS= read -r case; do
    echo $case
    matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -r "try;runinput=$case;matlab_script;end;exit" &
    if ((++count % 25 == 0)); then 
          if ! wait -n; then
               echo "ERROR - matlab failed!"
          fi
    fi
done <"$InputFile"
wait
```

Comment: So how would my batch file look like? Do I run the first command or the second example you posted?

Comment: Another question, for both of these example, will the result when using top be 25 different jobs? Or is it treated as a single job?

Comment: `Do I run the first command or the second example you posted?` One or the other. Sorry, but nothing will save you from understanding it. Read `xargs` documentation to understand it's options and learn basic bash scripting - research how to read from file line by line in bash, how to run processes in the background and how to wait for processes. `will the result when using top be 25 different jobs?` The __processes__ are run in the background. There will be like 26 __processes__ - 25 running running matlab and one running the shell or xargs. Research what is a process vs a thread.

Comment: `my batch file look like?` The script is written in __bash__ shell. A ["batch" execution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_processing) means an non-interactive execution - I have no idea if matlab reads input, the intention is to have non-interactive execution. Also `.BAT` windows cmd scripts are called ["batch" scripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) - I have no experience in windows CMD and this is not a `.BAT` script.

Comment: For the second script: if there are already 25 processes running from another similar script, does that mean that it won't run any processes? For some reason I had two of these command running at the same time, using different matlab scripts. one of them was already running, where the limit was 5 files, and ran another one, where the limit was 6. This resulted in only one process of the new batch command running at that instant, whilst the other 5 where still running from the old batch script.

Comment: `if there are already 25 processes running from another similar script, does that mean that it won't run any processes?` No. Processes do not know about other processes. Processes track only child processes.

Comment: Thanks @KamilCuk. One more question... how can I limit the %CPU usage to 100% for each process?

Comment: Limit cpu usage to 100%? Doesn't sound like a limit. Also why would you enforce a hard limit? Just make the processes be `nice`.

Comment: Looking back that's not what I wanted to do, but rather; how can I increase the amount of cores/memory available for a single job?

Comment: "increase"..."available"? In a usuall setup all available memory and all possible cores are "available" to all processes. Resources _restriction_ is configured separately, in many ways, but seldom. The priority is usually configured. To increase the amount of cores and memory buy a better computer. If your "single job" does not use the full cpu, that means you should _profile_ __the job__ and find the bootleneck - ie. concentrate on your process, not on the system...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where the `ssh` aspect of your code is, nor do I use `Matlab`, but if you want to keep 25 instances running at a time, I would suggest **GNU Parallel**, something like this:

```
parallel --dry-run -j25 -a inputfile.txt matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -r "try;runinput={};matlab_script;end;exit"
```

Comment: I dont have access to the parallel command in my machine unfortunately.

Comment: It's a Perl script that anyone can install in 10 seconds... http://oletange.blogspot.com/2013/04/why-not-install-gnu-parallel.html

Comment: I am accessing a remote server that has multiple cores available. I do not own this server, therefore I do not have the rights to install anything.

Comment: AFAIK, you don't need to install **GNU Parallel** on your remote, multi-core host in order to run jobs on it from your local machine using locally-installed **GNU Parallel**. I believe the only requirement is that Perl exists on the remote machine. Maybe @OleTange will confirm this? Or you could try it quite easily.